# Asynchronous subscriber ActiveMQ

Tags: asynchronous, activemq-classic, publish-subscribe

I know that in producer/consumer semantics (Queue as destination),where consumer can have a message listener attached to it. So whenever a message comes, listener will capture it through 'onMessage()' method asynchronously. I want to know is there any such asynchronous behaviour exist in publish/subscribe scheme, so that the subscriber do not need to call 'receive()' method to capture published messages.

Answer (score 1):

You can use asynchronous listener on Topics and Queues.  The only difference is the semantics of message delivery.  In the Topic case you subscriber needs to be active before a message is sent otherwise it won't receive it, in a Queue all messages are stored and distributed in a round robin manner.

You can of course create a durable subscriber to receive messages that are sent when the client is offline, just remember that the subscription needs to be created once before messages start to pile up for it when its down.

Comment: can u please give a sample code for asynchronous listener , ie, exactly i needed.

Comment: Exactly the same as you async consumer code on Queues, try Google.

Comment: Ya got it . WE can use DurableSubscriber here.Right?